# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem Only Utilizing 1 of 3 Cores

Tags: c#, asp.net, threadpool

I have lengthy call to a web service within an ASP.NET application that is being called through ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.  The call takes around 2 minutes to complete and sends about 2000 records to an external data store.  Everything seems to be running smoothly, except I have noticed that when these calls are made in the production environment running IIS7, only 1 CPU core is being utilized, and it is maxed out. How can I get this to balance the workload across all available CPU cores?

Comment: You've queued up 2000 items, or did you queue up one item containing 2000 records?

Comment: 1 item containing 2000 records.  The method called by the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem iterates over the 2000 records and sends each record to the third party data store via a SOAP client and service reference, it is the SOAP calls that really grind things to a halt.  Only 4 fields are sent for each record and they contain only small strings and integers.

Comment: So then... what is the question? You're queueing up 1 item, which means you're making 1 method call, you might as well not queue it up and simply call it. Basically, you're not doing it multithreaded.

Comment: When this method is called via ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem the machine running the application maxes out CPU 1, the other 2 cores on the machine sit idle.  I was under the impression that the thread pool would balance the spawned threads among these 3 cores rather than just tacking out one.  Is this not the case?  Do I need to change some configuration item to make this possible?

Comment: No, the thread pool will balance out the items you queue across cores. You queued up 1 item, thus it gives that 1 item to 1 core. If you queue up 2000 items, they will be "balanced out". Simply queueing up 1 item on the thread pool does not magically make that 1 execution path multithreaded.

Comment: So you must split into 2000 calls to QueueUserWorkItem

Comment: Ah, thank you.  I will wrap the queue process in a foreach and see what happens.

Comment: What version of .net are you using? Parallel.ForEach sounds like it might be what you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd460717(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using .Net 4.0+

If you have 2000 records and need to make 2000 related calls to a service of some sort, you can use this approach:

```
List<RecordType> records = GetMyRecords();
Parallel.ForEach(records, record => {
    MakeMyServiceCall(record);
});
```

This will run the MakeMyServiceCall method for each indivdual record in parallel; the parallel library uses the ThreadPool threads behind the scenes which will transparently distribute the load over the available cores.

Comment: Short answer: yes, you can use this for your DB insert. How you'd handle this really depends on how you're doing your insert: pure ADO, EF, etc